# Show that the centre of the circle $\dots$ approaches the point $\epsilon(s_0) = \dots$ - Elem Diff Geo Pressley

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition

**Help on getting started with this exercise**

---

Another approach to the curvature of a unit-speed plane curve $\gamma$ at a point $\gamma(s_0)$ is to look for the `best approximating circle' at this point. We can then define the curvature of $\gamma$ to be the reciprocal of the radius of this circle.

Carry out this programme by showing that the centre of the circle which passes through three nearby points $\gamma(s_0)$ and $\gamma(s_0 \pm \delta s)$ on $\gamma$ approaches the point
$$\boldsymbol \epsilon(s_0) = \gamma(s_0) + \frac{1}{\kappa_s(s_0)} \mathbf n_s(s_0)$$
as $\delta$s tends to zero. The circle $\mathcal C$ with centre $\epsilon(s_0)$ passing through $\gamma(s_0)$ is called the *osculating circle* to $\gamma$ at the point $\gamma(s_0)$, and $\boldsymbol \epsilon(s_0)$ is called the *centre of curvature* of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(s_0)$. The radius of $\mathcal C$ is $1/|\kappa_s(s_0)| = 1/\kappa(s_0)$, where $\kappa$ is the curvature of $\gamma$ $-$ this is called the *radius of curvature* of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(s_0)$.

Comment: Well, I would start by trying to derive a representation for the radius and center of a circle given by three plane points. In the second step I would insert the three given points on the curve into these considerations and would be excited to see what happens...

Comment: Do you have the same home work as Mary Star? see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481950/centre-of-the-circle

Comment: My concern with Vlad's proof is that $n(s_0\pm\Delta s)$ are normal to the circle but not necessarily to the curve $\gamma(s)$.

Comment: @arthur In general one can make argument that technically $n(s_0\pm\Delta s)$ is not _exact_ normal to $\gamma(s_0\pm\Delta s)$.
However, we do not need it to be _exact_.
In fact, you can think of $n(s)$ as vector connecting point $\gamma(s)$ on the curve with center $\epsilon(s_0)$ of osculating circle.
By definition of osculating circle $n(s_0)$ is normal to $\gamma(s_0)$, and $n(s_0\pm\Delta s)$ is close to $n(s_0)$.
Since we only look at difference $n(s_0\pm\Delta s)-n(s_0)$ and expand it in Taylor series, we only require $n(s)$ be smooth (vector) function, which it is by construction.

Comment: @Vlad - It suggests that the equations derived are true for the circle but not proven to be true for the curve $\gamma(s)$.
 In particular that the curvature of the circle and curve are equal.

Comment: @arthur The curvature of a curve at  point is defined in terms of osculating circle, so the curvature and a circle are indeed the same at a given point. As we take infinitesimally small step along the curve its curvature will not change much. In fact, I think one can show that the magnitude of change of curve is of the same order as the step $\Delta s$

Comment: @Vlad - The text book **defined** $\kappa = \left|\frac{dT}{ds} \right|$ but Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Precise_definition) defined it using a circle: $|\gamma'|^2 = x'(s)^2 + y'(s)^2 = 1$ then went on to state $\kappa(s) = |T'(s)| = |\gamma''(s)|$